# 405 error uploading text file on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpserver

I am using plain JavaScript and NPM [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). I am attempting to write/upload a plain text file to my localhost server directory.

I do not have routes or a controller set up, as I am just trying to bootstrap with the http-server package and JavaScript for simplicity.

JavaScript:

```
function upload_file(folder_name, file_name, file_contents) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

  req.addEventListener("load", callback);
  req.open("POST", "http://localhost:8002/" + folder_name + "/");
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(file_name +".txt", file_contents);

  req.send(formData);

  function callback() {
      console.log("Success");
  }
}

upload_file("data", "data.txt", "[1, 2, 3]");
```

When running, the following error occurs in browser console:

```
> index.html:349 POST http://localhost:8002/data/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

The http-server log:

```
[2021-06-08T18:22:05.828Z]  "GET /index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36"
[2021-06-08T18:22:18.732Z]  "POST /data/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36"
[2021-06-08T18:22:18.733Z]  "POST /data/" Error (404): "Not found"
```

Comment: Use Express for routes and multer for file upload very easily

Comment: You can't save directly to a folder like that; your server has to answer in some way, receive the POST request, parse the file in the body, then store it in a folder. Even if you use a framework like express, you'll usually still not write your own file upload code but use a library like multer for it. Simply put: it's not as easy as that unfortunately, but you don't have to reinvent the wheel either.